# Excel-VBA macro to transform cell content into a comment of another cell

Tags: vba, excel, comments

I have a seemingly simple goal to turn the content of column B into comments of column A.

[image: table before the macro]

[image: table after the macro]

I have tried using the following code from @Dy.Lee mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600673/add-comments-to-cells-using-vba), but unfortunately it gives me a Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error...

```
Sub Komentari()
Dim rngDB As Range, rngComent As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim cm As Comment, i As Integer
Set rngComent = Range("A1:A50")
Set rngDB = Range("B1:B50")

For Each rng In rngComent
    i = i + 1
    If Not rng.Comment Is Nothing Then
        rng.Comment.Delete
    End If
    Set cm = rng.AddComment
    With cm
        .Visible = False
        .Text Text:=rngDB(i).value
    End With
Next rng
End Sub
```

Can somebody, please, spot the mistake or suggest a better solution for this?

Comment: on which line is the error?

Comment: Try `.Text Text:=rngDB(i).text` to make sure it's a string?

Comment: @QHarr - error is on  .Text Text:=rngDB(i).value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go this way (explanations in comments):

```
Public Sub Komentari()
    Dim rng As Range

    With Range("A1:A50") ' reference comments range
        .ClearComments ' clear its comments
        For Each rng In .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through refrenced range adjacent not empty cells
            With rng.Offset(, -1).AddComment ' add comment to current rng corresponding comment range cell
                .Visible = False
                .Text rng.Value2
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Komentari()
Dim rngDB As Range, rngComent As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim cm As Comment, i As Integer
Set rngComent = Range("A1:A50")

For Each rng In rngComent
    i = i + 1
    If Not rng.Range("B1").Comment Is Nothing Then
        rng.Range("B1").Comment.Delete
    End If
    rng.Range("B1").AddComment (rng.Text)
Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following where you can use `Offset` to get the adjacent range, you drop the `=` when adding the text value to the comment, test that there is actually a value present first as well, and ensure you state the sheet to avoid implicit `Activesheet` reference.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Komentari()
    Dim rngComent As Range
    Dim rng As Range, cm As Comment

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngComent = .Range("A1:A50")
        For Each rng In rngComent
            If Not rng.Comment Is Nothing Then
                rng.Comment.Delete
            End If
            Set cm = rng.AddComment
            With cm
                .Visible = False
                If rng.Offset(, 1) <> vbNullString Then .Text rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Rather than add blank comments you could also flip this round to:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Komentari()
    Dim rngComent As Range
    Dim rng As Range, cm As Comment

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngComent = .Range("A1:A50")
        For Each rng In rngComent
            If Not rng.Comment Is Nothing Then
                rng.Comment.Delete
            End If

            If rng.Offset(, 1) <> vbNullString Then
                Set cm = rng.AddComment
                With cm
                    .Visible = False
                    .Text rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```