# Adding a note with VBA throws "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a created this macro with the Record Macro function of Excel:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Range("J2").Select
    Range("J2").AddComment
    Range("J2").Comment.Visible = False
    Range("J2").Comment.Text Text:="qsd"
    Range("L8").Select
End Sub
```

When running the sub function created like this:

```vb
Sub test()
    Call Macro1
End Sub
```

I get this error: "Object variable or With block variable not set".

The error is on line 3 according to the debugger:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add comments to cells using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600673/add-comments-to-cells-using-vba) - (You need to check if one exists first)

Comment: @braX - if a comment exists already tho, I think this code throws a RTE 1004.

Comment: You don't just check to see if it's `Nothing` first?

Comment: Meaning, if you run this code twice, you don't get RTE 91, but a RTE 1004... so I can't reproduce the issue. Though I don't disagree with you that one should check if a comment already exists first. I just can't repro specifically a RTE 91.

Comment: I can get RTE 91 is if I declare a Function `Range()` with a single string-typed parameter, but which does not return a Range object.  There may be other ways to get that though...   Do you have a method named `Range()` somewhere in your VBA project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed that there was already a comment.